# Scroll isn`t work , in angular + ionic 6 project

Tags: angular, ionic6

My code:

```
 <ion-grid>
<ion-row>
  <ion-col id="userinfos">
    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row>
       <app-userinfo></app-userinfo>
      </ion-row>
      <ion-row>
        <app-addition></app-addition>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col size="100%">
    <ion-grid id="gridcards">
      <ion-col *ngFor="let item of [].constructor(10); let i = index">
        <app-cards></app-cards>         
      </ion-col> 
    </ion-grid>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

I want to show some ionic-cards, but scrollbar is not working for me.

I try to use scrollbarmodule:

```
import { ScrollingModule } from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';
```

but isn´t work to

Some suggestion ?

Comment: use ion-row brfore ion-col Or Share more  code

Comment: I use nested grid, does not work in both cases, simple and nested

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert your entire code in "ion-content".

```
<ion-content>
<ion-grid>
<ion-row>
<ion-col>your text...</ion-col>
</ion-row>
</ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: It not work in my case, I have solved the problem with [.css](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css) ,and put the block inside : '<div class="w3-sidebar w3-light-grey w3-bar-block" style="width:100%">'